# Approximation of the resistance in a solenoid consisting of alternating sheets

Tags: solenoid

I thought it would be a nice idea if a solenoid would use sheets instead of wire to increase the coil density. In the picture, orange parts are placeholders for copper and blue for an insulator.

The issue is that the inner diameter can be drastically smaller than the outer diameter. This would also drastically increase the average circumference, which I use for resistance estimation. So it seems like ever increasing diameters will not decrease the total resistance anymore.

Unfortunately, I am not sure whether using the average circumference for length estimation of the coil windings is really accurate in such a case...

[image]

Comment: You should consider winding the other way, with the metal sheet parallel to the solenoid axis rather than perpendicular to it, like the low-voltage winding on a pole transformer, as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUO3o5JTGhQ).

Comment: neat video, love the core laminations going in!

Answer (score 5):

This is a well known design called the Bitter solenoid, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitter_electromagnet) on wikipedia. There are several links out from that article to analysis and design papers. It was invented in 1933 by, would you believe, Mr. Bitter.

A quote from that article ...

> Unlike a copper wire, the current density of a current carrying disc is not uniform across its cross-sectional area, but is instead a function of the ratio of the inner diameter of the disc to an arbitrary radius within the disc. The implications of this relationship is that the current density decreases with an increase in radius. As such, the bulk of the current is flowing closer to the inner radius of the disc. Large discs (i.e., disc with a large difference between their inner and outer radius) will have a larger discrepancy in the current density between the inner and outer portions of the disc. This will reduce the efficiency and cause additional complications in the system because there will be a more substantial temperature and stress gradient along the disc. As such, a series of nested coils is often used as it will more evenly distribute the current across a large combined area as opposed to a single coil with large discs.